# Cassandra 2.1, Datastax Java driver 2.1.1 - Custom authentication/authorization plugin causes NoHostAvailableException

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Environment is Red Hat, Cassandra 2.1, Datastax Java driver 2.1.1.

I have developed custom authentication/authorization plugins for Cassandra, and they work beautifully when I try them with cqlsh - I can see my plugins being called, users are authenticated/authorized accordingly, etc. - bottom line, everything works exactly as expected.

Then I tried to test using the Datastax driver. I'm connecting to Cassandra with:

```
public class CassandraConnection {
    private final Cluster cluster;
    private final Session session;

    public CassandraConnection(final String node, final int port) {
        this.cluster = Cluster.builder()
                .addContactPoint(node)
                .withPort(port)
                .withCredentials("someuser", "somepassword")
                .build();
        this.session = cluster.connect();
    }
    // Etc....
```

The call to cluster.connect() generates an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:196)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:80)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1145)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:149)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:225)
    at com.<company...packages...>.CassandraConnection.<init>(CassandraConnection.java:21)
```

Here is the puzzling part: although I can see my plugins being called when I test them using cqlsh, they are never accessed when I use the Datastax driver - I have added log messages in the beginning of each method, and they are never called. There are no errors in the logs indicating any sort of initialization problem, and I do see a message indicating that my plugins will be used.

That exact same client code works with no problem when:

1. I don't have my plugin running.
2. I use Cassadra's PasswordAuthenticator.

So, it looks like there is some problem with my plugins, but how can that be if 1) they work fine with cqlsh and 2) none of their methods are being called when the datastax driver is being used?

A couple of additional points - if I try to connect using Datastax's DevCenter, I see the same behavior as my client, with the exact same exception, so that rules out my (very simple) client code. I have also tried to:

```
    cluster.getConfiguration().getSocketOptions().setReadTimeoutMillis(10000);
```

before calling connect() as suggested in other posts, but that didn't help either - when I step through the client with the debugger, I see the error as soon as I call cluster.connect(), so it's not a time out issue either.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you catch the `NoHostAvailableException` in your client and inspect over its `getErrors()` field? That should give your more details about the error. You can also get that information in DEBUG logs.

Comment: All I see is: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042=com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect